# 1 Why can't "who played the mini-golf were the guests" be used to emphasize? 2 When no emphasis, it's grammatical, isn't it?

Tags: grammar, subjects, emphasis

Oxford Guide to English Grammar; John Eastwood; Oxford University Press 1994-09

Page 63

[image]

> b Look at these examples.
>
> *A technical fault caused the delay.*
>
> *The guests played mini-golf after tea.*
>
> We can emphasize different parts of the sentence.
>
> *What caused the delay was **a technical fault**.*
>
> *What the guests played after tea was **mini-golf**.*
>
> *What the guests did after tea was **(to) play mini-golf**.*
>
> *What happened after tea was **(that) the guests played mini-golf**.*
>
> NOTE
>
> a We cannot use who in this pattern. We must put a noun in front of it.
>
> ***The people who*** played mini-golf were the guests.
>
> NOT *Who played mini-golf were the guests.*

1 Why can't "*who played the mini-golf were the guests*" be used to emphasize? What's the difference between it and "*The people who played mini-golf were the guests*"?

2 When no emphasis, it's grammatical, isn't it? We can make such sentences, can't we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **what** can mean "that which" and thus it can be used as the subject of a verb.

> What goes around comes around.

But **who** in *modern* English does not mean "Those who" or "He who" except in literary uses, and sayings which have been frozen in time, as it were, like proverbs:

> Who pays the piper calls the tune.
>
> Who hunts doth oft in danger ride.
>
> Who uses games may often prove a loser.

In modern English, since the early 18th century, we use the word **whoever** when we want to use **who** as we use **what**.

> Whoever took my book should give it back.

P.S. With you miniature golf example, you could use **Those**:

> Those playing miniature golf were the guests.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that "Who played mini-golf" doesn't have a noun in front of the word "who".  When forming a sentence in this way there has to be a noun in front of the word "who".

It is the phrases starting "what" that are the exception:

You can say

> What started the fire was a match.

But that is a special case. You normally need a noun to modify. You can't say

> That started the fire was a match (*)
>   Which started the fire was a match (*)
>   Who started the fire was John (*)
>   When the fire started was 2:30 (*)

You can say

> The thing that started the fire was a match.
>   The person that started the fire was John.
>   The time when the fire started was 2:30  (note the order here)

Without emphasis you would say

> John started the fire.
>   The fire started at 2:30  (note the order)
>   The guests played minigolf.